# Significance of subcategories

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test

My data includes a total sum of around 30 different subcategories. If I want to find if the subtotal of these subcategories is significantly different from previous quarters I can run a chi square test of this years data against the average of previous quarters data, correct?

However, if I want to check if one category is significantly different, then do I simple compare it to the mean and sd of that categories' previous quarters?

For example, if this is my data:

| Subcategory | 2020Q4 | 2020Q3 | 2020Q2 | 2020Q1 | 2019Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SC1 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 7 | 12 |
| SC2 | 53 | 100 | 123 | 118 | 129 |
| subtotal | 55 | 106 | 127 | 125 | 141 |

How do I determine if the changes from each subcategory and for the subtotal are statistically significant?

Comment: It seems unlikely that chi-squared is the answer to your first problem as it is for frequencies not scores.

Comment: The subcategories are frequencies of events occuring.

Comment: I believe I would need to normalize the data for my expected values.

Comment: When you say "total" do you mean the bottom row?  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Yes, there are about 30 subcategories and the bottom row is the total. So I'm looking at 2020Q4 and trying to find any significantly different values for each subcategory as well as the subtotal